# C++/Qt: Get files in directory ordered according to sorting currently applied in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, filesystems

I would like to know if there is a way in Qt to obtain the filenames of files in a folder ordered according to the current Windows Explorer Settings for this folder. In Windows Explorer the user can sort files by many different criteria (e.g. name, capture date etc.) and I would like to be able to maintain maintain that order in my application.

UPDATE:

Perfect would be a cross-platform solution which also works in Finder on Macintosh and in Nautilus on Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't say this isn't supported but it seems likely that it's not. Since Qt is designed to work across multiple platforms, features that aren't available to all/many platforms are probably not supported (i.e., you may have to use Win32 specific functions).

Comment: You'd have to figure out where Windows Explorer stores its settings, and read them from your application so that you can sort the files according to same rules. Alternatively, you can embed Explorer in your application to use it to show directory contents.

Comment: Well, I don't actually want to embed a filebrowser. The application I'm working on can display images and you can go to the next/previous one. I wanted to match the order to the current sorting criteria for that folder in Windows Explorer. However, if that's not possible directly, do you know if Qt is able to sort directory contents by criteria such as capture date etc.?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175054/how-to-get-the-order-of-files-dirs-in-the-explorer?rq=1) suggests to use the [IFolderView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775606(VS.85).aspx) interface.

UPDATE:

Sorry, you might be looking for the [IFolderView2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775541(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, especially the [GetSortColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775533(v=vs.85).aspx) method:

```
HRESULT GetSortColumns(
    [out] const SORTCOLUMN *rgSortColumns,
    [in]  int cColumns
);
```

The returned [SORTCOLUMN structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759817(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to have the information you need:

```
typedef struct SORTCOLUMN {
    PROPERTYKEY   propkey;
    SORTDIRECTION direction;
} SORTCOLUMN;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like this could work for Windows. I'll implement something which works cross-platform first (using only Qt) and will afterwards have a closer look to your solution and add some Windows-specific code.